# Correct sign of rotation for projection of 3D points, matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation

I have a set of 3D points which I am projecting to image plane.

I am getting problem with rotation matrix.
Any help would be great.
Below is my code in matlab,

```
% adjusted plane through points XYZ=[X,Y,Z]p*3 % where p is no of points


%n*(XYZ)-d=0; Given plane parameters

-0,946467797198737  0,322785394989535   0,00288056369821191 28,3620026340107

% finding rotation matrix for [ 0 0 1]% xy plane projection


[U, S, V]= svd(n); 
C= [U(:, 2: 3), n];

R= rref([C, eye(3)]);
R= R(:, 4: 6);
```

% Test for correct R   % R*n

R*n=[ -0.0000,    - 0,    1.0000]'

**My question is about sign. Any method to get the correct sign ?
 I don't want to play with answer.(R*n). Problem is to get such R which gives you correct answer.**

Comment: where does `-0,946467797198737  0,322785394989535   0,00288056369821191 28,3620026340107` come from... also, what is -`0.0000 
- 0 
1.0000` is this the answer you are getting now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually your problem may not be so bad as it looks like.

More or less you still have a unit vector along `z`-axis. Just proceed your computations and ignore this kind of details (unless you really know how they may affect your computations, please note also that quite often a combination of inaccurate computations tends to balance themselves).

But if you really want (or need) delve in the details, just fine tune your computations like:

```
>>> x= [-1e-13 1e-13 1]';
>>> x(abs(x)< 1e-12)= 0
x =
   0
   0
   1
```

**Update**:
The `sign`you should worry about is the `det(R)`, thus you should add a check like:

```
>>> if 0> sign(det(R)), R= -1* R; end
```

Comment: I don't want to play with answer.(R*n). Problem is to get such R which gives you correct answer.

Comment: @shahbaba: Well, floating point computations are inherently inaccurate, thus it's ultimately your own judgement of the range of values you consider to be equal. Floating point computations won't give you exact results. Thanks

Comment: @ eat Problem is when i multiply R with XYZ, i get wrong rotation. So how can I make it correct.